# Does anyone know if you can register for Locale or TimeZone changes in a WINRT application?

Tags: events, timezone, locale, windows-8.1

Does anyone know how to register for Locale or TimeZone changes in a WINRT application?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a background task to run when TimeZone changes.

```
var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
builder.Name = "YourTask";
builder.TaskEntryPoint = "The.Background.Task.Implementation.Class";
builder.SetTrigger( new SystemTrigger( SystemTriggerType.TimeZoneChange, false ) );
builder.Register();
```

The main problem you will probably face however is that in Windows 8 the timezone will return the old value until the next reboot (although I'm not sure if that changed for Windows 8.1). The only way then to access the real new values for TimeZone is to use Win32 API – specifically this function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms724421(v=vs.85).aspx